# How to Explicit loading specific related entities for specific entities using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have two database tables :

1) **Locations** which has many Staffs

2) **Staffs** which has many Roles

If I want to load only related staffs which have Supervisor role for specific location I would do like this:

```
  var location = dbContext.Locations.Find(locationId);
  dbContext.Entry(location).Collection(b => b.Staffs).Query().Where(s => s.Roles.Any(r => r.Name=="Supervisor"));
```

My question is how to achieve explicit loading for related Staffs with supervisor role for all locations(I don't need for specific one as above)?

Comment: So you want all Staff with a supervisor role regardless of the location?

Comment: @Riv No, I want to load only Staff with Supervisor role for all locations inside locations table of course with locations data

Comment: EF is not designed to support partially loaded reference collections. So you will need to decide between loading all locations via include or separately querying the wanted location staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar for our implementation of the repository pattern. The key is to invoke `Load` at the end.

We had

```
public virtual void Load<TOut>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TOut>>> loadExpression, Expression<Func<TOut, bool>> filter) where TOut : class
{
    Context.Entry(entity).Collection(loadExpression).Query().Where(filter).Load();
}
```

So for your case you can try

```
dbContext.Entry(location).Collection(b => b.Staffs).Query()
    .Where(s => s.Roles.Any(r => r.Name=="Supervisor")).Load();
```

And then loop over all locations and load the references. Another option is to write an explicit `Linq2Entities` query for your case.

```
var locationWithStaff = (from location in dbContext.Locations
                         select new
                         {
                             location,
                             Staffs = (from staff in location.Staffs
                                       where staff.Roles.Any(r => r.Name=="Supervisor")
                                       select staff).ToList()
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I think it's a good trick to implement that

Answer (score 1):

You can use SelectMany to flatten the Staff list across all locations. Then you can filter based on the role

```
dbContext.Locations.SelectMany(b => b.Staffs).Where(s => s.Roles.Any(r => r.Name=="Supervisor"));
```

You could return an anonymous type in the SelectMany which would contain Location properties eg.:

```
dbContext.Locations.SelectMany(x => x.Staffs, (x, Staffs) => 
                   new { locationID = x.LocationID, SomeOtherProperty = x.OtherProperty , Staff = Staffs })
                  .Where(y => y.Staff.Roles.Any(z => z.Name == "Supervisor"));
```

Comment: This will only will load Staffs without the locations data , I think as @grek40 said "EF is not designed to support partially loaded reference collections"

Comment: @SimpleCode Do you need the entire Location entity or specific properties?

Comment: The entire location entities